# How can I get the correct sizes for UIViews created in storyboard during runtime

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, storyboard, size

I created a `UIView` using storyboard, set up constraints. When I ran the application, the interface looked fine. The view covered the entire screen as it was supposed to (I made the background color black so it's easier to see what's going on).

http://contentlibrary.sinaapp.com/View%20from%20Storyboard.png (I'm sorry I have to link images in like this, but the system says I need at least 10 rep to post images.)

However, when I tried to get the size of that view using `myView.bounds.size`. I got (600, 580), which is exactly the size that appeared in the storyboard's size inspector.

I created another UIView in code

```
var myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 600, height: 580))
```

and added it as a subview to the top-level view. It appeared but it didn't cover the entire screen like the view I created in storyboard. Both the view I created in storyboard and in code have the same value in their `.bounds.size`, but they appeared to have very different sizes on screen. (This picture is the view created in code. See there is white space at the bottom of the screen.)

http://contentlibrary.sinaapp.com/View%20from%20Code.png

Another interesting thing is, if I replace the above `UIView` with a `UIScrollView`, after the scroll view zoomed, it will update to the correct size.
I added a `UIScrollView` the same way I added the `UIView` using storyboard. I tried to print its size inside the delegate method `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`. It says (375.0, 647.0), which is the correct on-screen size for a view that covers the entire screen on an iPhone 6.

Judging from this, it seems that views that come out of a storyboard don't automatically update to the correct on-screen sizes.

So how do I get a UIView object created in a storyboard to update its size?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Would it be possible to include a screenshot of the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: @ndmeiri Sorry, the system says I can't upload images yet.

Comment: No problem. Can you post a link to the image by any change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're checking the size too early.

Try to put your code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method and see if it's going to change.

Comment: I tried. I tried checking the size in 3 different places: `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, and in the case of `UIScrollView`, `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:`. The first three were no good, the last one was, and I wonder why.

Comment: Did you try in `view**Did**LayoutSubviews`?

Comment: It worked. Really thx a lot. Looks like it's just a teeny tiny bit earlier than I was supposed to.